# What is the best way to represent the below data and highlight in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatables, bootstrap-grid

For example I have the following data,

```
var expectedValuesObj = [ "a.com","testid1","200.00" ];

var actualValuesObj = [
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],            
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["b.com","testid2","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["c.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","400.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"]
                    ];
```

by using the above data I need compare the data with **expectedValuesObj** against **actualValuesObj** , each and every value in those objects, if found any mismatch then I have to highlight  the records which are mismatching from the **expectedValuesObj** .

For e.g in **expectedValuesObj[0]** I will compare with **actualValuesObj[0]**
, I didn't find any mismatch because 
`actualValuesObj[0] = ["a.com","testid1","200.00"]`  all the values are matching with `expectedValuesObj[0] = ["a.com","testid1","200.00"]`. records

If any record found to be a mismatch then that record I have to highlight.

I preferring any good suggestion and idea using js, bootstrap, jquery, dataTables and laodash.

**Note :   For comparing two datasets, if you want you can change the dataFormat as per your comfortable, If you feel the given dataSet is not comparable.**

mainPage.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="conatiner"> This Div will have DataTable rendered by below js script file i.e File1.js , And this will Contain the child rows as well which will have the href link and I will open the new window on click of that link , it will open  the mainPage2.hmtl with File2.js loaded .</div>
</body>
<th layout:fragment="page-specific-js" th:remove="tag">
```

```
</html>
```

mainPage2.hmtl

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="conatiner"> Here I want render the Data which is mismatched  and and I have to highlight.  </div>
<script th:src="@{/resources/build/js/File2.js(v=${startUpTime})}" />
    </th>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So the logic which I'm expecting for comparing and highlighting can be in the File2.js.

File1.js

```
// Here I'm importing the jQuery  data tables lib's 
// implemented the script to display the Table with child rows in mainPage1.html
// I guess not necessary to add all the logic and DataTable formation here because it's a general syntax.
```

File2.js

```
var expectedValuesObj = [ "a.com","testid1","200.00" ];

var actualValuesObj = [
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],            
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["b.com","testid2","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["c.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","400.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"],
                        ["a.com","testid1","200.00"]
                    ];
// By using the above object after comparison, I want to display it in mainPage2.html by highlighting the mismatch records.
```

Comment: This is not even valid javascript. Your objects are missing property-names.

Comment: Updated the question,  Can you please see it now.  and for your information  data  format  you can change for your comfortable  .

Comment: when you said highlight in UI, how are you displaying this content?
post all your html and js so we can help

Comment: Can you please check now I have updated the question , and I have skipped the code which is general actaully  and now **File2.js** is expecting the solution for comparison  and highlighting  and you can use **File2.js** and **mainPage2.html** for any manipulation . @Webpandit

Comment: Better fit for https://ux.stackexchange.com/